# Can't access static css and js files from node.js docker container behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, static, public

I have several docker nodejs express apps being served behind a nginx reverse proxy.  Normally to access static files in an express app i simply create a public directory which contains css, and jss directories. I then access these files via app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
and then them where needed via

href=css/main.css

or src=/js/ascript.js

However with my recent use of NGINX I seem unable to refrence these static files this way.  I get not found errors, 404 errors, inccorrect mime type errors...etc

For someone who simply wants to reference a css file what am I supposed to do in this situation?

current nginx default.conf

```
upstream nodeapp1 {
    server nodeapp1:4200;
}

upstream nodeapp2 {
    server nodeapp2:4200;
}

upstream nodeapp3 {
    server nodeapp3:4200;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /nodeapp1 {
        proxy_pass http://nodeapp1;
    }
    location /nodeapp2 {
            proxy_pass http://nodeapp2;
        }
    location /nodeapp3  {
                proxy_pass http://nodeapp3;
            }
}
```

Comment: Did you mount `__dirname` in your docker container?

Comment: Your `proxy_pass` statements look invalid. They should look like `proxy_pass http://nodeapp1;`

Comment: Hi Richard thanks for the reply.  I typed them wrong here (have updated that now)  but they were correct in my actual conf file.  

CFrei, i haven't mounted __dirname.  how do I do that?  thanks.  When I console.log( __dirname) in the different node containers the come back defined